# What is the best way to read /format of GAE Datastore files?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, atom-editor

Working on porting GAE Datastore files to a new data base and need a fully readable, idealy csv format.
I am not getting the most readable information when i pulled my google datastore files into atom editor.  Is there a better way to read google datastore files or is there an atom plugin

Comment: i assume you are using the development version of datastore. that wont help you move a production datastore.

Comment: I've always used software to migrate entities from live to production or between namespaces. I have a PHP library that can help. What language are you using?

Comment: Have been using python django.